# How to disable CSS warnings in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Every time I save a CSS file, the *Error List* pane pops up with loads of warnings from the CSS file. For example

[image]

Most of those warnings are WTFs as far as I'm concerned.

How can I stop this pane from popping up *every time* I save the file?

I don't want to disable the pane popping up on real errors.

Note that I do not have *Detect errors* enabled in the CSS settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Web Essentials installed? This will get the warnings and set them to messages for you. If not I would recommend Web Essentials 2013.

Comment: Also in VS2013 you do get some more options. Its worth the upgrade overall.

Comment: @Ruddy, I just installed Web Essentials 2012 (2013 require VS2013), but the problem persists. I'll upgrade to 2013 at some point. Perhaps I'll just have to put up with this annoying behaviour until then.

Comment: They still appear as warnings? If so you can look in the Web Essentials settings to change it. (if that is now causing the problem)

Comment: @Ruddy, thanks. The _Validation location_ setting is set to _Messages_. I think these warnings are coming straight from VS itself, such that Web Essentials doesn't see them.

Comment: Regarding the question someone flagged as a potential duplicate, that applies to VS2008 which has different options.

Comment: Hmm, seems odd. Web Essentials seems to pick them up for me and set them to messages. Could you give me some CSS that will cause these warnings just so I can test some stuff. Also in VS2013 I can just turn off validation all together by setting it to false. This would also stop it from happening.

Comment: This should cause the first warning in my screenshot: `* { font-family: sans-serif; }`

Comment: That does not cause an error for me. Well the two ways I can get rid of the warnings (within VS2013) is to. Use Web Essentials - this set it to messages. And the other was turn CSS validation to false in VS settings. Other then that as I don't have VS 2012 anymore I cant be much more help. Hope you find an answer to the annoying problem.

Comment: I'm no expert on CSS, but if Visual Studio is throwing warnings at you for your CSS, instead of looking for a way to turn off the warnings, is it not better to investigate WHY VS thinks those things are worth warning you over?

Comment: @ToddBowles, I know enough CSS to know that many of the warnings I'm being shown are not worth my time. At any rate, I'm happy to see them -- just not every time I save the file. VS takes a good 20 seconds to populate the warnings, during which I cannot focus the editor as the focus is repetitively stolen by the warnings pane. This is what I'm trying to avoid.